# The meaning of "slighted" in the specific sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In Tennessee William's play, "The Glass Managerie", Amanda says:

> It wasn't enough for a girl to be possessed of a pretty face and a graceful figure although I wasn't slighted in either respect."

What is the meaning of "slighted" in this sentence?

Comment: If I asked you to pick one of the three meanings in the first definition on [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alighted), which one would you pick?

Comment: The word is not "alighted" but "slighted".

Comment: Unfortunately, there was a typo in the script I downloaded. The correct word is "slighted". But , again i don't understand the meaning. Does " be slighted in" mean "I wasn't gifted "?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a couple more sentences, so that there will be more context.

Comment: I would interpret this as Amanda saying that she did have a pretty face and graceful figure: replace "slighted" with "lacking". However, it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the meaning comes from the root of alight: light, i.e., she wasn't illuminated, lit up in either respect. But I would rather paraphrase it as:

(...) I didn't shine in either respect.

Comment: Any chance you could add some citations to back up your answer?

Comment: The free dictionary JMB mentioned above has one which has a more concrete use of the word: the sky was alight with stars.

Comment: Although, there might be an issue, alight in old english meant "to relieve", so if she wasn't pretty, the text could mean I wasn't relieved in either respect or criteria. I guess I would have to get more into the context. Sorry for the confusion, although I still feel more inclined to the more intuitive reasoning of the word.

Answer (score 3):

Slighted in this sense means to be denied of something.([source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/slight_3)) It is often used to refer to something you deserved or were promised.  In this context the character is saying she has both a pretty face a graceful figure, or is not lacking those features.  However, I don't believe it's common to use slighted in that context, I would use lacking instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure of the context this quote is coming from - after a little research the following two definitions make the most sense to me ([source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slighted))

> 1. To treat (someone) with discourteous reserve or inattention
> 2. To treat as of small importance; make light of

"Insulted" is a good synonym in this case.

It sounds like this person was told that being pretty wasn't enough - but that she was indeed pretty, so that she was not "slighted" (or insulted).

Answer (score 2):

It means she wasn't ignored in either aspect. So she was both yet it wasn't enough.